# excel use formula results in another formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A100)
```

I would like to use the results of formula `=ROW(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0))` in order to get the row number and use it in the UNIQUE formula, to get the changes dynamically.

the results should be:  `=UNIQUE(A1:A&*<results of =ROW(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0))>*)`

I need to use vba, or there is a way without it?

Comment: Something like `Unique( A1:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)-1,0))`  (untested, may need some adjustment)

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I can mention that INDIRECT will allow to convert a text to a cell reference: `=UNIQUE(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0)))`. Mentioning this in case people have similar question not solvable by the OFFSET formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OFFSET has a height parameter, you could use that instead directly: `=UNIQUE(OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1))`